# Oracle SQL creating virtual table from the variable collection

Tags: sql, oracle

i have 5 different tables , in all the tables bat_id is common column . i have list of bat_id and i have to check whether record exist for each bat_id in all 5 table expected example output as below

Example output:

```
------------------------------------------------------
l table1 l table2 l table3 l table4 l table5 l bat_id
l    0   l   21   l   5    l     0  l     1  l  452
l    5   l   3    l   0    l     0  l     15 l  123
l    235 l   0    l   0    l     0  l     87 l  586
-------------------------------------------------------
```

i have tried the below query but its working for only one bat_id at a time how to modify the below query to check record exist for  all the bat_id values in single query.

```
    declare
Bat_id Number 
&Bat_id = 476097
begin
select  
(Select count(*)  from Document where bat_id=&Bat_id) as table1,
(Select count(*) from Eds_task where bat_id=&Bat_id) as table2,
(Select count(*) from MI_Doc_Reads where bat_id=&Bat_id) as table3,
(Select count(*) from MI_Batch_Status where bat_id=&Bat_id) as table4,
(Select count(*) from Batch where bat_id=&Bat_id) as table5
from dual;
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your list of values coming from - what format is it in?

Comment: Hi Alex, this are the values of Bat_id = 458,456,3545,2123,877 for which i should get the count from all 5 tables

Answer (score 2):

Instead of selecting from `DUAL` you could select from a list of the `bat_id` values:

```
select (select count(*) from table1 where bat_id = t.bat_id) as table1
, (select count(*) from table2 where bat_id = t.bat_id) as table2
, (select count(*) from table3 where bat_id = t.bat_id) as table3
, (select count(*) from table4 where bat_id = t.bat_id) as table4
, (select count(*) from table5 where bat_id = t.bat_id) as table5
, t.bat_id
from (
  select bat_id from table1
  union select bat_id from table2
  union select bat_id from table3
  union select bat_id from table4
  union select bat_id from table5
) t;
```

You could also join all the tables together:

```
select count(table1.bat_id) as table1
, count(table2.bat_id) as table2
, count(table3.bat_id) as table3
, count(table4.bat_id) as table4
, count(table5.bat_id) as table5
, coalesce(table1.bat_id,table2.bat_id,table3.bat_id,table4.bat_id,table5.bat_id) as bat_id
from table1
full outer join table2 on table1.bat_id = table2.bat_id
full outer join table3 on table1.bat_id = table3.bat_id
full outer join table4 on table1.bat_id = table4.bat_id
full outer join table5 on table1.bat_id = table5.bat_id
group by coalesce(table1.bat_id,table2.bat_id,table3.bat_id,table4.bat_id,table5.bat_id);
```

You might want to check the explain plan for these queries with your data and see which performs better for your situation.

Given the five values that you provided, you can rewrite the query as:

```
select (select count(*) from table1 where bat_id = t.bat_id) as table1
, (select count(*) from table2 where bat_id = t.bat_id) as table2
, (select count(*) from table3 where bat_id = t.bat_id) as table3
, (select count(*) from table4 where bat_id = t.bat_id) as table4
, (select count(*) from table5 where bat_id = t.bat_id) as table5
, t.bat_id
from (
  select 458 as bat_id from dual
  union all select 456 from dual
  union all select 3545 from dual
  union all select 2123 from dual
  union all select 877 from dual
) t;
```

Comment: Hi , this are the values of Bat_id = 458,456,3545,2123,877 for which i should get the count from all 5 tables

Comment: Works perfect !! Many Thanks